# std::binary_search returns different result than std::find

Tags: c++11, vector, binary-search

Actually I couldn't see what's my mistake in my code but `std::binary_search` returns false for the element that have already added to `vec_barcode`. For comparison I tried `std::find` method & it works *properly*.

```
std::find(vec_barcode.begin(), vec_barcode.end(), "LOGUS") != vec_barcode.end() ? std::cout << "yes" << std::endl : std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
std::binary_search(vec_barcode.begin(), vec_barcode.end(), "LOGUS") ? std::cout << "yes" << std::endl : std::cout << "no" << std::endl;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your vector sorted?

Comment: Is `vec_barcode` sorted ?,

Comment: No. It's not sorted. So, `find()` requires a sorted vector?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski, `binary_search` requires a sorted collection and performs in O(log n); `find` performs a linear search in O(n)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki ohh, yes! Thanks a lot! İ forgot that. That's my mistake.